# Как установить pip пакет tinkoff-invest-openapi-client в Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

Вот что хочу установить, на Win10 установилось нормально тут ошибка pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/ tinkoff-invest-openapi-client
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что делать?

Comment: Последняя строка, ошибка 404, не может найти нужную страницу. Попробуйте скачать с сайта `pip` или поищите на `GitHub`

Comment: А в чём причина на винде ошибок не было?

Comment: Приведите ошибку в текстовом виде

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://github.com/Awethon/open-api-python-client) первый вариант - через `pip`, а второй - скачать прямо с гитхаба. Попробуйте второй

Comment: Попробую второй вариант спасибо